# What's the name of an algebra? is it isomorphic to $w_\infty \times w_\infty$?

Tags: lie-algebras, mp.mathematical-physics

Just as we know,
$w_\infty$:=span {${z^\alpha }\partial _z^\beta|\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z}, \beta\geq0$ }.

But, what's the name of the following algebra,
span {$\{{z^{\alpha_1}}{y^{\alpha_2}}\partial _z^{\beta_1}\partial _y^{\beta_1}|\alpha_i,\beta_i\in\mathbb{Z}, \beta\geq0\}$ }?

Is it isomorphic to $w_\infty \times w_\infty$?

Can one provide some references about this algebra? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is the associative algebra of algebraic differential operators on the torus $\mathbb{G}_{m,\mathbb{C}}^2$.  It is the tensor product of two copies of $w_\infty$, not the direct product.  That is, you should replace $\times$ with $\otimes$.

Comment: I'm very confused by this question and this answer.  In which sense is $w_\infty$ an algebra in this context?  I have always understood it as a Lie algebra. It may simply come down to what "span" means in this context.  Is it meant as a generating set?  or as a linear basis?  From your answer it seems you take it to mean the former.  Is this standard?


Comment: Usually, I think $w_\infty$ is an Lie algebra, though it seems that $w_\infty$ can be viewed as an associative algebra. The algebra spanned by {$z^{\alpha_1}z^{\alpha_2}\partial_{z}^{\beta_1}\partial_{y}^{\beta_2}$} should be Lie algebra. "span" means as a linear basis.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I think that my initial objection to your question was misguided and I've deleted my comment.  Sorry about the noise!
I now think that indeed what you wrote down is a Lie algebra.  It's the Lie algebra obtained from the associative algebra in Scott's answer via the commutator.
